# Can a Nikon D3200 use i-TTL wirelessly?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, wireless-flash

I have a Nikon D3200, and I'm thinking about buying a budget i-TTL capable flash to use with it, primarily off-camera. I was considering the YN565EXN, but the D3200 can't remotely control it with i-TTL, so I would need to pair it with a pair of YN-622Ns.

Would this pack work together correctly and provide i-TTL capability on my camera? Is there any better alternative (on the same price range)? Anyone has some experiences with this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a pair of YN-622N transceivers would allow you to use a YN565EXN flash, or any other iTTL flash without the need for a camera mounted "master" flash unit. Settings changes are made with the 3 small buttons on the camera mounted YN-622N.

For about the same money, I would recommend one YN-622TX-N transmitter and one YN-622N transceiver. The YN-622TX-N transmitter has it's own menu system which you will find much easier to use.

[image]

Comment: For a novice like me, it's a bit hard to know what combinations keep the TTL and which ones are manual only, as there is a lot of incompatible tech. Thanks for clearing it for me!